# Segmentation Fault on String C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, coredump

I am trying to do code for getting student name, surname and ID then printing it wtih stabil format. Example: ( Enter name and surname: "Alp David Oflas" Enter ID: "20110702037" then output should be like "OFLAS, Alp David, joined the Engineering in 2011 as 37st student.") So I'm trying to do with this code that except ID part but on repl.it I'm gettin "exited with non-zero status" error and when I'm tryin on Ubuntu I'm gettin "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". So can not solve this problem till 4 hours. Can you help me which part of code cause that error?

Note: I can not use any other function. I must do it with loops and comparison.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void output(char name[100],char ID[100]){

    char surname[100];
//Calculating name string's length//    
    int nameL;
    for(nameL=0;name[nameL]!="\0";nameL++);

    int i=nameL;
    int j=0;
    int flag;
    flag = "FALSE";
//Geting surname from value with decreasing i. It could be something like "Alp David Oflas" so we need just surname//   
    while (flag="FALSE"){
        if (name[i] == " "){
            flag="TRUE";
        }
        else{
            surname[j] = name[i];
            i--;
            j++;
            flag = "FALSE";
        }
    }
    surname[j]="\0";
//Previous surname just be like "salfO" so need to convert it// 
    char newsurname[100]; 
    int surnameL;
    for(surnameL=0;surname[surnameL] !="\0";surnameL++);
    int k=0;

    while (surname[k] != "\0"){
        newsurname[k]=surname[surnameL];
        k++;
        surnameL--;
    }
    newsurname[k] = "\0";

//Just capitalizing surname for dependant output//  
    int x=0;
    while (newsurname[x] !="\0"){
        if (newsurname[x] >= "a" && newsurname[x] <= "z"){
            newsurname[x] = (newsurname[x] -32);
        }
        x++;
    }           

    printf("%s",newsurname);

}

//Geting values from keyboard//
int main (){

    char name[100];
    char ID[100];
    printf("Enter name and surname:\n");
    gets (name);
    printf("Enter ID:\n");
    gets (ID);
    output(name,ID);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Investigate each warning.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz like (do not use "gets")

Comment: `int flag; flag = "FALSE"; while (flag="FALSE")` doesn't look right at all.

Comment: Hmm flag must be string right but still same error

Answer (score 0):

Solved... Problem on `"\0"` it must be `'\0'`.